# Is there full documentation about using Roslyn's IIncrementalGenerator?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

Roslyn Source Generator has now a IIncrementalGenerator interface that makes obsolete old ISourceGenerator implementations.

BUT IIncrementalGenerator looks "confusing" and lacks of Full Documentation. (No complex examples only news about it)

Any good documentation with tutorials to see complete potential?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Incremental generators are documented here:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md

There's also the following blog post, which documents the motivation behind `IIncrementalGenerator`:
https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-9-source-generator-updates-incremental-generators/